# How to add preloading animation in vue.js spa application using SVG

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I need to add a preloading animation for vue.js SPA application meanwhile files in the background are being loaded, using SVG and a progress bar. So instead of user seeing empty screen, he can see an animation. Something like gmail loading animation or https://jsfiddle.net/ Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VueJS has lifecycles. The most important for that are :
`beforeCreate, created, beforeMount, mounted`.
So, In your component, below the `data`, you can write some logic in these lifecycles.
So, for example in `beforeCreate` or `created` hook you can display your SVG loader, and then in `mounted` (inserted in DOM), you hide it.

Example :

```
 //MyComponent.vue
      <template>
         ...
      </template

    <script>
      export default {
        data() {
            return {
            article : {},
            user_id: null
        },
        created() {
         //Display your SVG
        },
        mounted() {
        //Hide your SVG
        },
        methods: {
        //etc,etc
        }
    </script>
```